# RepeaterBox scrollY property is not working in Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

RepeaterBox scrollY property is not working.
Actually, I am trying to set the scroll position to 0 for repeaterBox. 
Can any one help to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property called scrollY for repeatBox. scrollY is a property of ScrollView object.

In order to set the top position of repeatbox, you can use setTopIndex as in the
example below: 
http://docs.smartface.io/html/M_SMF_UI_RepeatBox_setTopIndex.htm

Answer (score -1):

this one works in my code

```
Pages.Page1.ScrollView1.scrollX=Device.screenWidth;
```

Comment: yes, it works for scrollview object, but not for repeatbox.